# Setting the form values in a post https request

Tags: haskell, networking, https, http-conduit

I want to perform a request with the certain headers, cookies and form values. Here is how I'm doing that:

```
  import Network.HTTP.Conduit
  import Network.HTTP.Types
  --.......omitted


  configReq r = r { method = methodPost
  , requestHeaders = (requestHeaders r) ++ [
      (DS.fromString "Referer", DS.fromString "https://server...."),
      (DS.fromString "SomeHeader2", DS.fromString "fdsfdsfds")
    ]
  , requestBody = RequestBodyLBS (Aeson.encode $ Map.fromList [("email", "my@mail.com"), ("password", "7890")])
  , secure = True
  , cookieJar = [myCookie]
 }
```

This seems like it should work. But it doesn't because a server returns `400` --> `"X-Response-Body-Start","Invalid input."` no matter what the email and the password are. Note that this is not a request which perform something per se, it is an **authentication** request (the same one you send when you click "login" button) that's why it has `email` and `password` form values (the same as on its `/login` page).

I figure that even so the **form values** `email` and `password` are in the request, they have to be set differently, meaning they have to be not in `requestBody` but in some different place.

So for now the question is where do I have to put `email` and `password`  if not in `requestBody` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the web server is expected URL encoded form data, not a JSON request body. You can use the aptly-named [urlEncodedBody](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-conduit-2.1.2.3/docs/Network-HTTP-Conduit.html#v%3aurlEncodedBody) function for that purpose.

Comment: am I sending a JSON? I am aware about urlEncodedBody but it returns a whole request, whereas I need to setup headers, cookies and form data manually. How can do I do that?

Comment: `urlEncodedBody` *modified* a `Request` that you provide it. You set all of the headers and cookies, and then `urlEncodedBody` will set up the request body and modify any other headers that need to be set. And yes, you're sending JSON; that's what `Aeson.encode` is doing.

Comment: would you mind showing me a simple example of using urlEncodedBody which applicable to my case? Yes, I've seen the examples at hoogle but none of them helped me to figure out what I should do.

Comment: `urlEncodedBody [("email", "my@mail.com"), (..., ...)] $ r { method = methodPost, ... }`